# FormData com Axios no Node.js

Tags: node.js, spring, axios

Quando tento fazer uma requisição usando form-data com o node, a aplicação em Springboot que recebe a requisição diz que ela não tem "boundary". E quando coloco qualquer valor em "boundary", a aplicação não reconhece os dados dentro de form-data.

Segue o código:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const api = require('../services/api')

module.exports = {

    async assina(req, res) {

        const { signatario, algoritmoHash, perfil } = req.body;
        const { fw_credencial, kms_credencial, kms_credencial_tipo, 
        auth_token } = req.headers;
        const { path } = req.file;

        const dadosAssinatura = {
            "signatario": signatario,
            "algoritmoHash": algoritmoHash,
            "perfil": perfil
        }


        console.log(req.file)

        const data = new FormData();

        const contents = fs.readFileSync(path);

        console.log(typeof(contents));

        console.log(JSON.stringify(dadosAssinatura));
        console.log(data)

        

        try {
            const response = await api.post('/kms/assinaturas', data, {
                headers: { 
                    "kms_credencial": kms_credencial,
                    "kms_credencial_tipo": kms_credencial_tipo,
                    "auth_token": auth_token,
                    "fw_credencial": fw_credencial,
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=ronaldo" 
            }
            })
            
            console.log("DEU CERTO");
            return res.json(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("erro");
        }

        return res.json(req.body.signatario)

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, vi que você está utilizando a lib form-data no seu projeto.
Se você estiver em um projeto que suporte ES6 sugiro usar o import abaixo, agora caso continue usando o require, acho que somente precisa fazer a segunda etapa adicionando no headers.

```
import * as FormData from 'form-data';
```

Feito isso, você pode manter como está no seu código e somente adicionar no headers da requisição que você está tentando enviar o seguinte código:

```
headers: {
   ...formData.getHeaders(),
}
```